# why can't I import a mysql dump with triggers into mariadb

Tags: mysql, mariadb, swisscomdev

We plan to migrate our stuff into swisscom app cloud and therefore need to import existing MySQL dumps into MariaDB - so far no big deal...

But the import of the dumps fail as soon as a trigger should be imported.

e.g. I have a dump with this single trigger:

```
DELIMITER ;;
/*!50003 CREATE*/ /*!50017 DEFINER=`root`@`localhost`*/ /*!50003 TRIGGER trg_mytable_insert AFTER INSERT ON mytable FOR EACH ROW
                    BEGIN

                         INSERT INTO mytable_audit (id, fk_X)
                         SELECT a.id, a.fk_X FROM mytable a WHERE a.id = NEW.id;

                    END */;;
DELIMITER ;
```

I trigger the import like this:

```
mysql --user xxxxxxx -pxxxxxxx -h 127.0.0.1 -P 13000 CF_E7D2D18F_A20B_4FFF_89A7_XXXXXXXX < trigger.sql
```

causes this error:

```
ERROR 1227 (42000) at line 2: Access denied; you need (at least one of) the SUPER privilege(s) for this operation
```

The strange thing is, that with liquibase we are able to create triggers with the exact same user. So what special privileges are required to import a trigger via `mysql` CLI?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
CREATE*/ /*!50017 DEFINER=`root`@`localhost`*
```

You’re seeing this message because MariaDB in Swisscom App Cloud doesn’t provide the SUPER privilege, and thus you cannot set up a trigger or view to run as a different user — only a user with SUPER can do that.

see [Using MySQL triggers and views in Amazon RDS](https://www.percona.com/blog/2014/07/02/using-mysql-triggers-and-views-in-amazon-rds/) for a workaround with `sed`.

> I recently had an opportunity to migrate a customer from a physical
>   server into Amazon’s RDS environment. In this particular case the
>   customers’ platform makes extensive use of MySQL triggers and views. 
>   I came across two significant issues that prevented me from following
>   Amazon’s documentation, which basically states “use mysqldump” but
>   doesn’t call out a specific method of dealing with MySQL triggers and
>   views.

```
mysqldump -h hostname -u username -ppassword –single-transaction database_name | sed -e 's/\/\*[^*]*DEFINER=[^*]*\*\///' | mysql -h hostname -u username -ppassword database_name
```